# Как убрать растяжение width 100% в ie7?

Tags: internet-explorer, вёрстка

Всем привет! 
Хотел бы спросить у Вас как можно решить баг с растяжением `width` в `ie7`.

Есть такая [страница](http://biactors.ru/).

На ней три картинки это будущая карусель.
Вопрос с рамкой для картинок во всех браузерах кроме ie7 они отображаются нормально, как надо, а вот там они растягиваются на всю ширину.

Подскажите если если кто-то сталкивался?

Comment: Завтра на работе посмотрю, у меня там есть оригинальный ие7. 

Бегло посмотрел Вашу вёрстку: зачем всё так сложно? зачем дополнительные два дива для РАМКИ ФОТОГРАФИИ? Почему не использовать старый добрый border?

Comment: Дело в том что у рамки должны быть скругленные углы, для этого дивы, чтобы, чтобы все растягивалось. И еще по скольку карусель будет по кругу вращаться, то нужно чтобы рамка сама автоматически растягивалась в процессе движения.

Comment: используй `outline` или `border`. Они также могут быть скруглены и растягиваться

Comment: @Сахарок это же ие7

Comment: @Genson Нашел решение для скругленных уголов в ie7. 
Вот здесь: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=732

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте `width: table` .
Как-то странно у вас всё это реализовано... Судя по коду, вы начинающий. Если хотите сделать что-то эффектное, то попробуйте готовые варианты (например, доступные плагины `jQuery`).

Comment: Я пока не находил таких готовых плагинов для такой карусели, если посоветуете буду благодарен.